# How to create a function that can be evaluated for specific values

Tags: functions

I have been trying to create a function to compute a field and perform operations with it, however when I try to define it I have used:

```
Subscript[Field, E][x, y] = -Grad[(x^2 + 2 x*y^2) E^(-x^2 - y^2), {x, y}]
```

However, I always recieve:

```
Set::write: Tag List in {E^(-x^2-y^2) (2 x+2 y^2)-2 E^(-x^2-y^2) x (x^2+2 x y^2),4 E^(-x^2-y^2) x y-2 E^(-x^2-y^2) y (x^2+2 x y^2)}\[InvisibleApplication](x,y) is Protected. >>
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Incorrect syntax. See [Defining Functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referred to in the comment (with link) there is a syntax error. The following defines the function, the negative gradient and visualizes it.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x^2 + 2 x*y^2) E^(-x^2 - y^2)
g[x_, y_] := -Grad[f[u, v], {u, v}] /. {u -> x, v -> y}
sp = StreamPlot[g[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamStyle -> Red];
cp = ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];
scp = SliceContourPlot3D[
   z, {f[x, y] - z == 0}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   ImageSize -> 300];
Row[{Show[cp, sp, ImageSize -> 300], scp}]
```

[image]

Note: the gradient is evaluated and then values passed to the arguments.